# nodejs: Where is image upload stored?

Tags: image, node.js, upload

I did a tutorial for nodejs image upload.

Question: Where does nodejs store the uploaded image?

I work locally mit localhost:8888
(I'm new to nodejs and programing)

```
requestHandler.upload = function( response, request ) {
console.log( "Request for 'upload' is called." );

var form    = new formidable.IncomingForm();

console.log( "Preparing upload" );


form.parse( request, function( error, fields, files ){
    console.log( "Completed Parsing" );

    if( error ){
        response.writeHead( 500, { "Content-Type" : "text/plain" } );
        response.end( "CRAP! " + error + "\n" );
        return;
    }
console.log("the path is: " +files.upload.path);

    fs.renameSync( files.upload.path, "/tmp/" + files.upload.name );

    response.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type" : "text/html" } );
    response.write( "received image <br />" );
    response.end( "<img src='/show?i=" + files.upload.name + "' />" );

   });
};
```

Comment: I don't know much about formidable, but `console.log("the path is: " +files.upload.path);` ?

Comment: I wanted to check where the file is located, and it says: /tmp/7fa95b95b9f......  I don't understand that

Comment: Well, isn't that obvious? It's in /tmp/7fa95b95b9f... That's the path.

Comment: It is uploaded into /tmp folder in Linux, filename is randomly chosen.

Comment: OMG I did not see the difference between my tmp and the tmp of the system, you are right, now I found it, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Node.js (the platform) doesn't store the files anywhere. The body of the request is simply received as `Buffer`s of [`'data'`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_data).

[`formidable`](https://npmjs.org/package/formidable) does, though. It scans and `parse`s the request `'data'` for you and saves any `multipart` "*files*" within [`form.uploadDir`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#api):

> ```
> form.uploadDir = process.env.TMP || process.env.TMPDIR || process.env.TEMP || '/tmp' || process.cwd();
> ```
>
> The directory for placing file uploads in. You can move them later on using `fs.rename()`. The default directory is picked at module load time depending on the first existing directory from those listed above.

Comment: That's an interesting piece of that code: `'/tmp' || process.cwd();` :)

Comment: @freakish Well, I don't think it's meant to actually be used as code. :) It's just documentation written in code-form.

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in the tempory files of my windows system.